# Unable to get complete patch with git

Tags: git, diff

In a `git` repo, I had new file *additions*, file *removal/renames* with 
*modifications* as usual. When I took a `git diff` to patch in another
view, I did not get all the new/removed files. Then I tried  with
`--cached` option, then, I got some different file set, but still, 
not the complete set of all changes + file additions and removals.
(I had done a `git add` and `git rm`)
I also tried `--diff-filter=ACDMRTUXB`, still didnt help!
Am I missing some other option ? all I want is to get the full set of
diffs in 1 command.
I have `git version 1.6.2.4` on my Linux machine.

--

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:

- `git diff` shows unstaged changes in tracked files (you added the file at some point, but haven't added these specific changes)
- `git diff --cached` shows staged changes (ones you've already added)

It sounds like you have a mixture of staged and unstaged changes in your working copy.  If you want to get them all into the same patch, you can either:

- unstage your changes: `git reset` will empty the staged changes from your index but leave them in your working copy, so `git diff` will give you the complete patch now
- stage all the changes: just `git add` the remaining files to your index: then `git diff --cached` will give you the complete patch

Comment: hi, is `git reset` safe to do on a working view?. On the other option, do you mean, do a `git add` on files even if there are just modifications?, or rather a `git add` from the top directory ?

Comment: First, the default behaviour of `git reset` is to reset the index (so git forgets which working copy edits you staged already) but not touch the working copy itself.  So, no files are affected, they just show up as *modified* again when you run `git status`.  See the [manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) for details

Comment: @vyom - Secondly, I'm assuming you've already run `git add` on some specific files, otherwise you wouldn't have a mixture of staged and unstaged edits.  In the second case above I'm suggesting you `git add` the specific edited files which aren't already staged.  I seldom add from the top directory, since I may have temporary junk in my working copy that shouldn't be versioned.

Comment: Yes, I had done `git add/ git rm` for the files that were being added/removed. What I was unable to get was, all the changes in 1 diffset. I will try the `reset`, I have never tried before.

Comment: Doing a `git add` on even the modified files, and then taking a `diff --cached` worked. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to have some changes to a file staged (added to the index), and other changes _to the same file_ un-staged and only in your working copy. You can do this deliberately, like [this](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/14/interactive-adding.html) or [this](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/15/piecemeal-staging.html), but you can get the same result just by editing a file further _after_ you `add` it.